# How can i update the UI on a ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart

Every time i first run the code the list view don't show up, but if i do a hot reload the listView appear

```
List<JsonFetch> player = [];
String query = '';
Timer? debouncer;

class HomeScreen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen2> createState() => _HomeScreen2State();
}

class _HomeScreen2State extends State<HomeScreen2> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    init();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    debouncer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void debounce(
    VoidCallback callback, {
    Duration duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
  }) {
    if (debouncer != null) {
      debouncer!.cancel();
    }

    debouncer = Timer(duration, callback);
  }

  Future init() async {
    final players = await DataFromJson.getPlayer(query);

    setState(() => player = players);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: const [
          LeftSide(),
          RightSide(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I think the problem could be in the `RightSide` because is in a different class from `HomeScreen2` and i don't pass some information correctly. I am a newbie on flutter and i can't reach the problem.

```
class RightSide extends StatefulWidget {
  const RightSide({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RightSide> createState() => _RightSideState();
}

class _RightSideState extends State<RightSide> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    print(size);
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [AppColor.secondaryColor, AppColor.primaryColor],
                stops: const [0.0, 1.0])),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            WindowTitleBarBox(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(child: MoveWindow()),
                  const WindowButtons(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: player.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final p = player[index];
                return Shard(p);
              },
            ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please remove the list, string and timer on top and add them in the state class above the `initStatete` override.

Comment: initially I did this, but it didn't work and even if I tried to pass variables to the class it gave me an error